# How to reuse .java entities with JHipster?

Tags: java, jpa, jhipster

I have a quantity of (commented) JPA entities as .java files that I want to reuse with a brand new JHipster generated project.
They are documented so I dont want to regenerate them.

So far, from exchanging on the chat, an option would be to use JHipster-UML.
Meaning I must use my javas to produce a valid XMI file then used by JHipster-UML to produce JSON describing the entities. Then the JSON is to be used by JHipster.

The first option I thought of was to generate text to be fed to JHipster (with << on unices)

Is there something cooking for that usage (say ".java import") ?

What is advised as of today ?

Thank you

Comment: So you've got Java class files that you want to reuse?  Why not repackage them into a JAR and use them that way?

Comment: Hi Makoto, I'm new to JHipster but what I've read is that JHipster uses JSON class descriptions produced by the jhipster:entity command (stored in .jhipster folder).
Therefore, my .class files should be of no use.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with converting java entity files to json, is that only certain entity options are supported by jhipster. So, it's not the conversion that's difficult, it's adding the support for the options to the generators.

I use [JDL](https://jhipster.github.io/jhipster_uml.html#jdl), which isn't automatic but is still fairly simple to create existing entities and relationships.

Comment: Thank you elk-tamer, it looks like a more elegant solution.
I will look at that as soon as back to the office in a few days.

Answer (score 0):

I did a similar approach in a recent project. I used an UML tool and imported my classes and used JHipster-UML afterwards to create the json-files. 
Then, I copied the java files into the package `domain` (where JHipster will generate your entity classes). 
Then, I run Jhipster to generate the entities. Since JHipster checks, if the file is already present (and/or identical), I just use "do not overwrite".

Obviously, this means, that your entity-classes must follow the conventions of Jhipster, so that the rest resources and services are working.

Comment: Thank you Indivon. This is a year old now but I remember other issues were due to multiple levels inheritance, also collections ...